# Display Friendly Error Message When using Decorators in Models

Tags: validation, asp.net-core

New to ASP.NET Core.

I have a view:

```
<form asp-action="LogIn">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="EmailAddress" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="EmailAddress" class="form-control" style="min-width:350px" />
                <span asp-validation-for="EmailAddress" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Password" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" style="min-width:350px" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Enter" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I have this Model for it:

```
public class Subscription
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long SubscriptionId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*")]        
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string Password { get; set; }        
}
```

So, when a User types in an email address that is not validated by the regular expression I get the error message:

[image]

How do i over-ride this 'default' error message to say (for example):

**Email Address is Invalid**

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `ErrorMessage` property to the `RegularExpression` attribute like this-

```
[RegularExpression(@"\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*", ErrorMessage = "Your friendly message goes here")]
```